# Restore arrow to select removed with 'appearance'

Tags: html, css, forms

This may seem simple but I'll be darned if I can't get it to come back. My form has a read only state and edit state, which I change via JS. I want my form elements to not look like form elements when in the read only state. Removing the arrow is as simple as setting 'appearance: none' on the select but there doesn't seem to be a way to get it back for my edit state, and I've tried all the options. Maybe I missed one, or maybe there's a better way to do this. I'm considering falling back to Bootstrap dropdowns. Selects are a pain! Still, I would love to keep my form elements if at all possible.

```
<style>
    select {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        border: 0;
        background-color: #ccc;
    }
    form.editing select {
        -webkit-appearance: normal;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        background-color: white;
    }
</style>

<form class="readonly" id="form">
    <select name="test">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
    </select>
</form>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#edit").on("click", function(){
           $("#form").toggleClass("editing");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried, or at least the HTML you're working with.

Comment: please add an [mcve] to your question - otherwise we might be just guessing at answers here

Comment: "I want my form elements to not look like form elements when in the read only state."  What do you want the elements to look like?  Would it solve your problem to put some `div` you like next to the `select` and see the `select` while editing and the `div` when not editing?

Comment: The CSS should make it pretty clear what I want them to look like, but that's really not my question. I'm simply trying to restore the select element's down arrow in the read only state. In other words, what is the opposite of 'appearance: none;'?

Comment: Try `appearance: normal`.  [`appearance`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_appearance.asp) does not have very good browser support.  Also for your reference: [caniuse appearance](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-appearance).